# TextView not aligned in iOS 6

Tags: iphone

I have taken two textview in my xib.also giving same frame by programmatically .But when i run my project it is not showing me as i set in xib.All textviews are starting from x=0,y=0.`txt_summary.frame = CGRectMake(9, 118, 302, 410);
    txt_title.frame = CGRectMake(67, 8, 233, 81);`Please help me.Thanking you in advance...

Comment: Are you sure you turned Auto-Layout feature off in the .xib?

Comment: can you please tell me how to set off?i don't know how to set.i just drag textview and put where i want to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the method. Open your xib file.

Go to File Inspector, and disable Auto-layout.

[image]

Comment: oh yes...its working...superb man...gud job n thank you so much